# Solr SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType and MySQL DIH

Tags: mysql, solr, spatial, dataimporthandler

I have Solr 4.3.0 set up and I'm trying to use the SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType for a spatial field. The data comes from a MySQL geometry field, and the SQL query returns the data for that field using `AsText()`. The basic query looks like this:

`SELECT AsText(data_geo) as data_geo FROM table;`

The data_geo field is defined in schema.xml as:

```
<field name="data_geo" type="location_rpt" indexed="true" stored="true" 
    multiValued="false" />`

<fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType" 
    spatialContextFactory="com.spatial4j.core.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory"
    geo="true" distErrPct="0.025" maxDistErr="0.000009" units="degrees" />
```

When I perform a basic non-geofiltered query, the response looks like this:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
    "indent": "true",
    "q": "*:*",
    "_": "1384375755970",
    "wt": "json"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "date_modified": "2013-11-13T16:53:57Z",
        "id": "165733_0_1",
        "data_geo": "POINT(43.87910249999999 -103.4590667)",
        "_version_": 1451618631810023400
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Adding a {!geofilt} eliminates all results, even though the point above is within 10km of the point I'm filtering on:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1,
    "params": {
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "*:*",
      "_": "1384376149059",
      "wt": "json",
      "fq": "{!geofilt pt=43.879103,-103.459067 sfield=data_geo d=10}"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? I don't know if the issue is on the indexing side or the query side; I couldn't find any documentation on using MySQL with the Solr DataImportHandler and the new SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType.

Thanks!

Comment: For longitude = 3,  latitude =43, how do we index a POINT or a CIRCLE,  and how do we use geofit ?

Answer (score 2):

Easy: The problem is that you are indexing your data with latitudes and longitudes reversed. If you choose the WKT format as you have done, then it's "POINT(X Y)" order.  You may also do "Y, X" if that suits you.  I'm surprised Solr (actually Spatial4j) didn't complain about you using a Y value of -103 which is clearly out of bounds. There is a boundary check.  The error would be InvalidShapeException "Bad Y value -103.4590667 is not in boundary ..." (and then the boundary)

Comment: Thanks! I guess some data cleanup will need to happen in MySQL. That will take some time, so I'll check back in once that's done.

Comment: For longitude = 3,  latitude =43, how do we index a POINT or a CIRCLE,  and how do we use geofit ?

Comment: `BUFFER(POINT(X Y), D)` ; all units are in degrees (360 around the globe).